# what do the colours of the wires on stereo speakers signify from old TVs and laptops?

Tags: audio, speakers, laptop, tv

I have a few laptop and a TV stereo speakers salvaged from old electronics in my possession and I have noticed a pattern that I cannot understand. Both the left and right of these speakers have two wires but on one speaker the wires are red and black whilst on the other speaker the wires are black and white. Does anybody know what this means? Is there a difference between the left and right speakers?

thanks

Comment: Probably denoting right (red) & left (white) channels. In a stereo system, there is a difference between right & left, especially when watching a movie as stereo give a spatial sense to the listening experience.

Comment: Oddly in audio, red is right (seems so WRONG to a sailor) and white is left. Black is signal return, i.e. usually ground.

Comment: @user_1818839: In North America, red right is normal - our bouyage system is red on the right when returning to harbour.

Answer (score 1):

[Phono sockets](https://3wisemonkeys.co.uk/a-guide-to-audio-video-connections-rca-phonoscartamphdmi/) have white and red colours that denote left and right audio channels (an example of the same colours used on your speakers): -

[image]

And here's [another example](https://www.bluecinetech.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/rca-composite-connection.jpg): -

[image]

It also extends to [phono extension cables](https://www.amazon.co.uk/kenable-Phono-Extension-Socket-Audio-Dark-Blue/dp/B00NCSTEDQ): -

[image]

So, the two speakers referred to have wires that carry the same basic information (with black being the common neutral connection).

Red and white are also the colour codes for [phono cartridges](https://www.henleyaudio.co.uk/cartridge-installation) used in turntables: -

[image]

And [DIN plugs and sockets](https://audiokarma.org/forums/index.php?threads/tonearm-5-pin-din-plug-wire-sequence.839261/) also use the same colours: -

[image]

Comment: Any chance we could get you to provide citations or attributions for all of those nice images you copied?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson done!

Answer (score 1):

Remember for audio R is Right and Black is floating common wire.(gnd) that leaves White as left always used in phono jacks R/W.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the only difference is the wire color, to distinguish between left and right speaker and between positive and negative terminals when assembling the devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard. Red and black is common but other less prominent colours are popular (but usually for reasons of domestic aesthetics which don't apply in your case).

Stereo speakers need to be wired in-phase to avoid a "hole-in-the-middle" effect on the audio panorama. If the speakers are wired out of phase there will be some cancellation at low frequencies which will affect the bass. This is the primary reason for having some form of identification on the wiring.

In your case I would expect the blacks to be the 'common' or 'negative' (common nomenclature even though audio is AC) and the red and black to identify left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Just to combine all the comments and answers in one place:

The black wire is the "negative" wire. The red and white wires are "positive" wires.

From the audience perspective, the red and black wires are for the right speaker and the white and black wires are for the left speaker.

What does the polarity mean on a speaker wire? Well, if you apply a small DC voltage to a speaker, when the voltage is positive, the voicecoil moves toward the listener. By "positive" I mean applying the DC voltage to the red or white wire and using the black wire as ground.